# RecyclerView items goes behind AppBar on fast scroll

Tags: android, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

Having problem with list scroll and CollapsingToolbarLayout. I am trying to have smth like profile info at app bar layout, and some list data at the bottom. When I scroll slowly it collapse perfectly, but if I will scroll fast list items will go behind AppBar before it will collapse. Any ideas how to prevent it? I want my appbar to be smth like list header.

Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3MjLbKudbSdLTFKNHZFa2I5UGc

Layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks!